# Custom window proc in a separate file

Tags: c++, winapi, global-variables, subclassing

I'm currently learning winapi, and would like to get some advice on how to set up a custom control using different window procedures.

Let's say I have 20 buttons. I want each button to respond differently when the mouse hovers over it. Say, an "exit" button draws a red rectangle when hovered, or blue when some other button is hovered.

So, I have set up a custom control procedure that handles mouse clicks, mouse hover, and such, and is stored in `custom.cpp`. In `main.cpp`, there is a `MainProc()` that "links/assigns" `hwndButton` to `ButtonProc()` using

```
CustomProcHandler = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(hwndButton, GWL_WNDPROC, (long)CustomProc)
```

main.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char g_szClassName[] = "Applicaton";
static HWND hwnd, hwndButton;
static HINSTANCE hInst;
static WNDPROC buttonProcHandler;


LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    MSG msg;

    hInst = hInstance;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, 0);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 20, 20));
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInst, 0);
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 600, 400,
        NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(msg){
        case WM_CREATE:
            button = CreateWindow("button", 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 10, 10, 32, 32, hwnd, 0, hInst, 0);
            buttonProcHandler = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(hwndButton, GWL_WNDPROC, (long)ButtonProc);
            break;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default: 
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

custom.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(msg){
        case WM_CREATE:
            break;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            break;
        default:
            return CallWindowProc(buttonProcHandler, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the button disappears... but when I move `buttonProc()` inside of `main.cpp` then everything works fine.

So, I am guessing I did something wrong when declaring global variables like `static WNDPROC buttonProcHandler`.

I know what I am doing is entirely wrong, and that there is a better way of doing it.  I just don't know what that is.

Can anyone can help/teach me the standard way of creating custom procedures?

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `static` works. Since you include `main.h` in separate `.cpp` files, each `.cpp` gets *its own local copy* of the `static` variables that `main.h` declares. If you want multiple `.cpp` files to share global variables with each other, do not declare them as `static` in a shared `.h` file, define them one time in a single `.cpp` file and then use `extern` declarations in the shared `.h` file.

Comment: Also, when you start subclassing multiple buttons, you will need separate `WNDPROC` variables for each button, as you must paass the correct previous `WNDPROC` to `CallWindowProc()`, you can't use a single `WNDPROC` variable for all of the buttons. The best way to handle this is to wrap each button in a class that handles the subclassing for the single button it holds.

Comment: You should use `SetWindowLongPtr` and `(LONG_PTR)ButtonProc` otherwise pointer value may be cut.

Comment: Wonderful, it worked like charm! Thanks to you sir Remy Lebeau!

Comment: @VTT: Unless you are hellbent on supporting Win9x and Windows 2000, you should not do any of those. The correct way to subclass a control is to call `SetWindowSubclass`, as explained in [Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx).

Comment: @VTT ok thanks i'll look into that. I was just doing basic stuff like the basic learners do. But yeah, if thats how its done nowadays - then, might as well join the crowd. Thanks chief!

Comment: @VTT: Acknowledging pointer truncation issues does not turn this into a viable scheme for subclassing controls. Suggesting to use API calls capable of passing pointer-sized values is correct, but simply isn't applicable in context of this question.

Comment: @VTT: It were, if the goal was to evangelize writing unreliable code. That's not one of my goals, hence the comment to not use `SetWindowLong[Ptr]` at all, but to call [SetWindowSubclass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) instead. I'm having a hard time following, what point you are trying to make here.